# Unable to run OpenVPN client on wifi in UBUNTU 18.04.3 Bionic 64 bit

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

I installed `OpenVPN`, configured the client and used the following commands to install network-manager "nmcli" and tried to connect the client.

Getting time out error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-openvpn

$ cd ~/
$ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file client.ovpn

$ nmcli connection up client
```

### I don't know where I've gone wrong.

Following is the result of network manager nmcli command:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file client.ovpn

Warning: There is another connection with the name 'client'. Reference the connection by its uuid '290ab809-dcb5-457d-889e-f3913bc74f91'
Connection 'client' (290ab809-dcb5-457d-889e-f3913bc74f91) successfully added.
```

Comment: Can you share the ouput of `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file client.ovpn`?

Comment: Thanks for the support. Added the result of command $ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file client.ovpn in the above question.